# PyQt5 - error while finding spec

Tags: python, pyqt5, pythonpath

I have come across many similar questions, so it appears to be a common problem. However, there are some variances among the question specifics and nothing I have found has worked for me so far. My issue is that I have installed PyQt5 and Python 3 on OS X El Capitan and that every time PyQt5 is run, I receive an error.

> `//anaconda/bin/python3.5`: Error while finding spec for '`PyQt5.uic.pyuic`' (`<class 'ImportError'>`: No module named '`PyQt5`')

As you can see, I've been using Anaconda Continuum Analytics and that is now the default Python. Unfortunately, this obviously isn't the package which includes PyQt5:

```
$ which python
//anaconda/bin/python
$ which python3
//anaconda/bin/python3
$ which pyuic5
/usr/local/bin/pyuic5
```

I am somewhat familiar with using Python but have no experience with the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable or changing which version of Python is 'default' (I've got Python 3 installed, Anaconda and the stock 2.7).

How to fix this error?

Comment: You may have more then one installation of python. I assume that the PyQt5 installler you used does not know about anaconda. Ask the anaconda people how to add PyQt5 to their build of python.

Comment: Yes, I have three installations. The native OS X (Python 2.7), Anaconda Continuum, and Python 3.0. Thank you for your suggestion @BarryScott, I will contact Anaconda.