# PyCharm Attach to Process failed

Tags: pycharm

I have PyCharm Community Edition 5.0 installed on my Windows.

When I ran Python from command line, and tried to use PyCharm to attach, it failed with following error:

```
Attaching to a process with PID=5860
C:\Python34\python.exe -mpydevd_attach_to_process.attach_pydevd --port 36748 --pid 5860
C:\Python34\python.exe: Error while finding spec for 'pydevd_attach_to_process.attach_pydevd' (<class 'ImportError'>: No module named 'pydevd_attach_to_process')
```

But looks like the module had already installed with PyCharm:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 5.0\helpers\pydev\pydevd_attach_to_process`

Is there anything I can do to fix it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38410777/pyqt5-error-while-finding-spec

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33216679/usr-bin-python3-error-while-finding-spec-for-virtualenvwrapper-hook-loader

Comment: @Hack-R Had tried install virtualenvwrapper and set VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON as an environment variable but still not working.